# How to save csv file which contains ≥ sign?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

```r
a<- paste0("\U2265",80) 
b<- paste0("\U2265",80)
data <- data.frame(a,b)
write.csv(data, "C:/NMPED Data Transformation/Newfile.csv", row.names = F, na = "",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

But the output showing as :

```
a    b 
80  80
```

expected output is:

```
a   b  
≥80 ≥80
```

my output of sessioninfo() is

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 haven_2.5.0       ggmap_3.0.0       readxl_1.3.1      RODBC_1.3-19      data.table_1.14.2 forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.7       purrr_0.3.4      
readr_2.1.1       tidyr_1.1.4       tibble_3.1.6      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
tidyselect_1.1.1    lattice_0.20-45     colorspace_2.0-2    vctrs_0.3.8         generics_0.1.1      utf8_1.2.2          rlang_0.4.12        pillar_1.6.4       
glue_1.5.0          withr_2.4.3         DBI_1.1.1           sp_1.4-6            dbplyr_2.1.1        modelr_0.1.8        plyr_1.8.6          jpeg_0.1-9         
lifecycle_1.0.1     munsell_0.5.0       gtable_0.3.0        cellranger_1.1.0    rvest_1.0.2         RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3 tzdb_0.2.0          fansi_0.5.0        
broom_0.7.10        Rcpp_1.0.7          scales_1.1.1        backports_1.3.0     jsonlite_1.7.2      fs_1.5.1            rjson_0.2.20        hms_1.1.1          
png_0.1-7           stringi_1.7.6       grid_4.1.3          cli_3.1.0           tools_4.1.3         bitops_1.0-7        magrittr_2.0.1      crayon_1.4.2       
pkgconfig_2.0.3     ellipsis_0.3.2      xml2_1.3.3          reprex_2.0.1        lubridate_1.8.0     assertthat_0.2.1    httr_1.4.2          rstudioapi_0.13    
R6_2.5.1            compiler_4.1.3
```

Comment: It's the 2nd time you ask this question after deleting the 1st question. In a comment to [the deleted 1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075536/which-encoding-we-have-to-use-to-save-a-r-csv-file-which-contains-≥80) I said that this is a OS specific encoding issue and that you should **please update the question with the output of `sessionInfo()`**. Please do so, it's difficult for us answer without it.

Comment: Hello @RuiBarradas .Now I have updated with output of sessioninfo()...can you please help me in this

Comment: Update to R 4.2.0, and this problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Use the locale `English_India.utf8`.

In the example below I first set your locale (since mine is different) and the wanted symbols are not printed.
Then I set `LC_CTYPE = "English_India.utf8"` and the greater-than-or-equal-to symbols are there.

In the end I reset the original locale.

```r
old_loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")

a <- paste0("\U2265",80) 
b <- paste0("\U2265",80)

data <- data.frame(a, b)

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English_India.1252")
data
#>     a   b
#> 1 =80 =80

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English_India.utf8")
#> [1] "English_India.utf8"
data
#>     a   b
#> 1 ≥80 ≥80

write.csv(data, "~/Temp/Newfile.csv", 
          row.names = FALSE, 
          na = "",
          fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", old_loc)
#> [1] "Portuguese_Portugal.utf8"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello @RuiBarradas when I am trying to change  Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English_India.utf8")
I am getting this error
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English_India.utf8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "English_India.utf8" cannot be honored

Comment: @murali That means that the UTF-8 locale is not supported on Windows. This long standing problem was solved with R 4.2.0. Try to [**update R (it's for free)**](https://cran.r-project.org/) and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot you solved  my issue @RuiBarradas